# Complex pandas isin function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]: 
    uid   a   b
0   111   1   2
1   111   2   3
2   111   4   5
3   111   6   7
4   111   5   8
5   222   0   9
6   222  11  12
7   222  13  11
8   222   2   1
9   333  14  16
10  333   3   2
11  333  16  19
12  333   3   4
13  444  21  20
14  444   9   5
15  444  20  24
16  444   5   6
```

I want to check if values in `b` are present in `a`,vice-versa only if the `uid` is same.
I used `isin` :

```
df[(df.b.isin(df.a))|(df.a.isin(df.b))]
```

but this goes through all values and does not give me the desired output.

Desired output:

```
 Out[49]: 
    uid   a   b
0   111   1   2
1   111   2   3
2   111   4   5
4   111   5   8
6   222  11  12
7   222  13  11
9   333  14  16
11  333  16  19
13  444  21  20
14  444   9   5
15  444  20  24
16  444   5   6
```

Comment: Why for `444` isn't ` 444   9   5` and `444   5   6` in the desired result

Comment: @EdChum sorry my bad edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and apply [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
print (df.groupby('uid').apply(lambda x: x[(x.b.isin(x.a))|(x.a.isin(x.b))]))
        uid   a   b
uid                
111 0   111   1   2
    1   111   2   3
    2   111   4   5
    4   111   5   8
222 6   222  11  12
    7   222  13  11
333 9   333  14  16
    11  333  16  19
444 13  444  21  20
    14  444   9   5
    15  444  20  24
    16  444   5   6

print (df.groupby('uid')
         .apply(lambda x: x[(x.b.isin(x.a))|(x.a.isin(x.b))])
         .reset_index(drop=True))
    uid   a   b
0   111   1   2
1   111   2   3
2   111   4   5
3   111   5   8
4   222  11  12
5   222  13  11
6   333  14  16
7   333  16  19
8   444  21  20
9   444   9   5
10  444  20  24
11  444   5   6
```

Comment: Thank you I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Boolean indexing inside of a lambda function applied to a groupby, learning something new everyday.